# Stacking a column vector and an array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Suppose I have a column vector

```
B = [[5], 
     [7]]
```

and an array

```
A = [[1, 1, 1, 1], 
     [247, 121, 1, 314]]
```

What I want to is to couple the top row of `A` with its counterpart from `B` (and similarly for the bottom ones) and then evaluate a function `func(a,b)` on these pairs. So for example if the function is the `scipy.special.betaln` I would like to calc the following

```
C = [[betaln(1,5)  , betaln(1,5)  , betaln(1,5), betaln(1,5)  ]
     [betaln(247,7), betaln(121,7), betaln(1,7), betaln(314,7)]]
```

which yields:

```
C = [[-1.609 , -1.609  , -1.609, -1.609 ]
     [-32.070, -27.1618, -1.945, -33.732]]
```

In reality I will have an array A with around 27,000 columns and rows anything from just a couple to a couple of hundreds. Hence, B will also be a vector of length 1 or two to a couple of hundreds. I have stuck on this and I dont know whats the best (fast) way to do it. I am doing that on tensorflow, thus A and B are tensors, but numpy arrays would also work just fine. (or maybe generators? I dunno...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`scipy.special.betaln`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.betaln.html) is a [ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) which means it can accept arrays (or in this case, even list-of-lists) as input. The values in `A` and `B` will be [broadcasted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for you automatically:

```
In [205]: special.betaln([[1, 1, 1, 1], [247, 121, 1, 314]], [[5], [7]])
Out[205]: 
array([[ -1.60943791,  -1.60943791,  -1.60943791,  -1.60943791],
       [-32.0707512 , -27.16180903,  -1.94591015, -33.73292188]])
```

Calling `betaln` once on the entire arrays will be much much faster than calling `betaln` multiple times -- once for each pair of scalar values.